# How to solve this differential equation numerically in Python?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python

I am trying to solve a differential equation in Python:
    $$y'' + 2\frac{y'}{x} + (1 - \frac{e^{-x}}{x} - \frac{l(l+1)}{x^2})y = 0$$
I have initial conditions at $x=0$ as:
    $$y(0) = a$$
    $$y'(0) = b$$
$a$ and $b$ are some known constants and they will be constrained by $l$. I tried using Euler forward method but solution was unstable. I tried Runge-Kutta 2nd order method but again the solution was unstable. What method should I use so that I will get a stable solution?

Comment: The "industry standard" is Runge-Kutta 4. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Arthur I haven't tried. I just want to ask, because I am new in this,, that does that work in such cases?

Comment: See dopri5 option at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

Comment: You asked about the same differential equation in [MSE question 2785298](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2785298) but using Mathematica instead.

Comment: @Somos Yeah, and it worked on mathematica. But, I wanted to know that how would I implement it on python. Because mathematica doesn't show the method it used.

Answer (score 3):

This equation is stiff for $x\ll1$ because the dominant term is the first derivative (you can check the coefficients w.r.t. the first one, which is one).

The Runge-Kutta methods are explicit and they are not suitable to solve these kind of stiff equations (however, for $x\gg 1$ they fit perfectly).

You should go for implicit methods. Try the simplest one: [backward Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method).

Comment: It is not only stiff, but downright singular at $x=0$.